# Disable WinForms ListViewItem Tooltip for long texts

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, tooltip

I have created `ListView` and added two item with long text.
when I select first item second item`s text is clipped, for example "MyIte....".

So when move mouse pointer under this item, I see toolTip with all text.

How to disable this tooltip?

Set property `ListView.ShowItemToolTips = false` doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` shows item tooltips when receives a `WM_Notify` message with `TTN_NEEDTEXT` lparam. So to disable tooltips, you can process `ListView` messages and if the control received that message, neglect it.

You can inherit your ListView and override `WndProc`, but as another option, you can register a `NativeWindow` to receive your ListView messages and this way you can filter messages.

**Implementation**

```
public class ListViewToolTipHelper : NativeWindow
{
    private ListView parentListView;
    private const int WM_NOTIFY = 78;
    private const int TTN_FIRST = -520;
    private const int TTN_NEEDTEXT = (TTN_FIRST - 10);
    public struct NMHDR
    {
        public IntPtr hwndFrom;
        public IntPtr idFrom;
        public Int32 code;
    }
    public bool TooltipEnabled { get; set; }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_NOTIFY && !TooltipEnabled)
        {
            var nmHdr = (NMHDR) m.GetLParam(typeof(NMHDR));
            if (nmHdr.code == TTN_NEEDTEXT)
                return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    public ListViewToolTipHelper(ListView listView)
    {
        this.parentListView = listView;
        this.AssignHandle(listView.Handle);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

To disable tooltips for a ListView you can simply create an instance of above class:

```
ListViewToolTipHelper helper;
helper = new ListViewToolTipHelper(this.listView1);
```

To enable tooltips again:

```
helper.TooltipEnabled = true;
```

**Another workaround**

You can disable the tooltip for `ListView` using this workaround, but the side effect is all other tooltips in form also will be disabled this way.

```
ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
toolTip.SetToolTip(this.listView1, "dummy text");
toolTip.Active = false;
```

Comment: Thank you for unswer. Sorry for my English(